# How to pass data to aherf in laravel blade from js variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel

I sent a ajax request to get data from controller with json format. something like this-

```
return response()->json($data);
```

I received the response from laravel view with a variable like this-

```
var rpr_data_id = response.id;
```

Now I want to pass this variable to one of my data. Button is written in this format-

```
<a href="{{url('rpr/')}}"> <button>send</button></a>
```

Question: how to pass the js variable in laravel blade anchor tag?

Comment: You could add an id attribute to the a tag and access the a tag then in your js code, did you try that?

Comment: I used this-
$('#modal-rpr-name').text(response.name);

and in view I did like this.
<span id ="modal-rpr-name"></span>
it's working fine but main problem is to pass id in anchor url tag. 
something like this- <a href={{sample/link/id want to pass here}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `attr()` method for that.

Assuming your link can be easily selected:

```xml
<a id="your-anchor-id" href="{{ url('rpr/') }}">send</a>
```

```js
$('#your-anchor-id').attr('href', $('#your-anchor-id').attr('href') + response.id)
```

On a side note, you shouldn't put a `<button>` inside an `<a>`.

Comment: Thanks working now.
I did this-
<script>
    var jsVariableLink = document.getElementById('js-variable-link');
    jsVariableLink.href = "/example/" + jsVariable;
</script>